# How to acces to the active JMS Connection/Session in Spring Boot that @JmsListener uses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I'm trying to recover messages that are sent back to the ActiveMQ queue due to the destination being unreachable. I'm avoiding the re-delivery policy as it doesn't fit my requirements. I need to recover these messages at exact time in my application with session.recover().

I'm currently using a close to default jms configuration for spring boot that enables the use of the @JmsListener annotation. However I cannot find a way that to get grab the handle of the active jms session this annotation uses?

Comment: spring doesn't expose used session .. take a look at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  and  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.AsyncMessageListenerInvoker

Comment: That is not correct; Spring JMS has a `SessionAwareMessageListener`, which the `@JmsListener` annotation infrastructure implements; see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add a `Session` parameter to the listener...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55038881Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55038881Application.class, args);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "so55038881")
    public void listen(String in, Session session) {
        System.out.println(in + ":" + session);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("so55038881", "foo");
    }

}
```

and

```
foo:Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:host.local-52659-1551967879238-4:1:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@5bad3a2d
```

Comment: Just checked the documentation again, can't believe how I missed that....